# where is index value or hexa value of bitcoin in source code?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip44

Registered coin types
These are the default registered coin types for usage in level 2 of BIP44 described in chapter "Coin type" above.

All these constants are used as hardened derivation.

```
index   hexa    coin
0   0x80000000  Bitcoin
1   0x80000001  Bitcoin Testnet
```

where we can find index, hexa of bitcoin for BIP44 ? how to calculate it ?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md

> ### Registered coin types
>
> These are the registered coin types for usage in level 2 of BIP44 described in chapter "Coin type".
>
> All these constants are used as hardened derivation.
>
> | index | hexa | symbol | coin |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0 | 0x80000000 | BTC | Bitcoin |
> | 1 | 0x80000001 |  | Testnet (all coins) |
> | 2 | 0x80000002 | LTC | Litecoin |
> | 3 | 0x80000003 | DOGE | Dogecoin |
> | 4 | 0x80000004 | RDD | Reddcoin |
> | 5 | 0x80000005 | DASH | Dash (ex Darkcoin) |
> | 6 | 0x80000006 | PPC | Peercoin |
> | ... | .... | .... | ... |
> | 99999997 | 0x85f5e0fd | EQ | EQ |
> | 99999998 | 0x85f5e0fe | FLUID | Fluid Chains |
> | 99999999 | 0x85f5e0ff | QKC | QuarkChain |
>
> Coin types will be added only if there is a wallet implementing BIP-0044 for desired coin.

Comment: It is hard code maintenance right ?